# How to use only Socks Proxy in Firefox using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

i'm writing tests in selenium and tried to use only socks for proxy. Here is the code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
proxy = "localhost"
port = "5900"
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks", proxy)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_port", port)
profile.update_preferences()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:\Program Files\MozillaFirefox\geckodriver\geckodriver.exe", firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get("https://[xxx:xxx:xxx:xxx]")
```

But when I checked in Firefox. the proxy is set for all HTTP, FTP, etc instead of only Socks. Here is the image
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEPyl.jpg)

I know I am missing something Basic here. What is it?

Answer (score 1):

profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_port", int(port))